# Kotlin idiomatic way for extracting logic that gets executed when a value is null

Tags: kotlin

I have something like this in Kotlin, repeated in several places (and please bear in mind that I'm relatively new to the language and I'm still figuring out what's the best/ more idiomatic way to do things):

```kotlin
class SomeClass {
    fun someMethod(c: Context) {
        val id: String? = c.someValue?.someId
        if(id == null) {
           return someResult("some message")
        }
        doSomething(id)
    }
}
```

I would like to find an idiomatic way of extracting

```kotlin
if(id == null) {
  return someResult("some message")
}
```

and still be able to use the value of `id` without having to help the compiler determining its value is not null. How can I do this idiomatically in Kotlin?

Comment: What do you mean by "extract"? You want to extract the if statement into a function, and be able to access a non nullable `id` after calling the function? Did I understand correctly? Can you show some pseudocode of what you'd like to do?

Comment: Yes, correct! Pseudocode could be what's posted in the answer below, only it doesn't work because I need to pass the non nullable `id` to `doSomething`:

`
class SomeClass {
    fun someMethod(c: Context) {
        val id: String? = c.someValue?.someId ?: return someResult("some message")
        doSomething(id)
    }
}
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use kotlin elvis operator it works the same as `if(id == null) {...}` :

```
class SomeClass {
    fun someMethod(c: Context) {
        val id: String = c.someValue?.someId ?: return someResult("some message")
        doSomething(id)
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't do that because then I need the `id` to be passed to `doSomething` as a `String`, not as a `String?`.

Comment: @SilviaPina Change `val id: String?` to `val id: String`

Comment: Yes! So it's really simple after all, thank you!!

Comment: @SilviaPina I forget deleting `?`, it should be `val id: String`